# hg command to see the changeset prior to an hg fetch

Tags: mercurial

What mercurial command can you use to see the changeset prior to changeset xyz?

If you do `hg log -r :xyz` you see all the changesets prior to (and including) xyz - listed in ascending order. But I'd like to easily see just the prior changeset.

---

Update: Really what I'm after is this: If I do an `hg fetch`, what command can I use to see the changeset PRIOR to the the changesets that were pulled in by the fetch?

`hg log -r :xyz` where xyz is the first changeset pulled in by the fetch works but it returns the entire list of prior changesets where I just want the most recent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it.  Once you've pulled (and fetch is just pull + either update or merge) there is no record of what you had before the pull and what you just got from the pull.

You should do `hg incoming` before you pull to see what you will get.

Also, stop using `fetch`.  The acts of pulling and updating and merging are completely separate and doing them in a single commands provides inadequate error reporting and just confuses things.  The command is disabled by default and there's talk of removing it entirely.  Merging *is* coding, and it shouldn't be hidden.

**Expanding to Show cases you can't cover**

If before fetching your history is this:

```
[A]-[B]-[C]
```

and you (against all advice) `fetch` and get `[D]` you now have:

```
[A]-[B]-[C]-[D]
```

And you can see exactly what's new with:

```
hg diff -r tip-1
```

or with:

```
hg diff -r "parent(tip)"
```

But if starting again with A,B,C you fetch and get D,E yielding this:

```
[A]-[B]-[C]-[D]-[E]
```

there is no command you can run to see "what changed" without having previously written `[C]` down on a post it note.

If, on the other hand your repo started out looking like this:

```
[A]-[B]
  \
   -[C]
```

and after fetching you have this:

```
[A]-[B]-[D]
  \
   -[C]-[E]
```

there's no single command that will tell you "what changed".  Similarly, if before pulling your repo looked like this:

```
[A]-[B]-[C]
```

and after fetching you got this:

```
[A]-[B]-[C]-[E]-[F]
  \            /
   -[D]-------/
```

where `[F]` is the new ill-advised auto-merge changeset fetch created then the command:

```
hg diff -r C
```

will tell you what's new, but there's no way to look up 'C' without having previously written it down.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any links regarding the "talk of removing [fetch] entirely"?  Would like to forward that to the sdlc team at my company..

Comment: But if do know the first changeset you pulled in from a fetch, is there an hg log command that will show you just the prior changeset to that?  The command would return the tip prior to the fetch..

Comment: Sure, if you know the first changeset you got via fetch you can use the `hg log -r "parents(THATCHANGESET)"` that many others answers have suggested (including one of mine I deleted when it started looking like you were asking for something else after your edit.

Comment: That fetch is a bad idea has been on record for a long time: selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2009-June/026320.html Yesterday in #mercurial I saw wistful talk about deprecating and killing it, but mpm seems too into backward compatibility to pull the trigger on it.

Comment: Parent doesn't really work..   I could have changesets 1-2-3-4-5 in trunk and do an `hg fetch ..\feature-rel`, if the first changeset in feature-rel is 6, 6 could have a parent of 4 where I want a command that will return 5..  so I can do an `hg diff -r 5` to see a list of all files changed by the fetch (inc merge)

Comment: I get what you're saying but I really think you're missing the point: once you're talking about a non-linear history there is no single command that is going to tell you what all changed via a fetch.  If '6's parent is '4' and that '6' changed is the diff between 6 and 4 and 5 has nothing to do with it.  And none of this applies when fetch pulls down multiple changesets because you immediately lose the knowledge of what is new and what was already there.  Use 'incoming' before 'pulling', and stop using 'fetch'.

Answer (score 0):

I assume xyz is a changeset in hash form. Try:

hg log -r :xyz-1

That should work to list just the changeset prior to 1

Comment: Changeset is not in hash form - that is the numeric id

Answer (score 0):

With the parentrevspec[1] extension installed, you can use the git-like syntax below. Depending on your shell, the quotes may not be necessary.

```
hg log -r 'xyz^'
```

1. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ParentrevspecExtension

Comment: Nice catch Martin, I added that to my standard config so long ago I'd forgotten about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is meant by prior.  Your question could mean you might just want the parents of the changeset.  These you would get easily with

```
hg parent -r xyz
```

This does not need fancy new versions of mercurial.

> hg parents [-r REV] [FILE]
>
> show the parents of the working directory or revision
>
> Print the working directory's parent revisions. If a revision is given via
>       -r/--rev, the parent of that revision will be printed. If a file argument
>       is given, the revision in which the file was last changed (before the
>       working directory revision or the argument to --rev if given) is printed.
>
> options:

```
-r --rev       show parents of the specified revision
--style     display using template map file
--template  display with template
--mq        operate on patch repository
```

Comment: That works - but it appears my question was missing some details.  I updated my question..

Comment: I should of said that does return the parent but in the case of a fetch that is slightly different that what I'm after.  See updated q.